# Axios response.data comprises an error, although the data seems to be correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, redux-toolkit

Currently I am learning to code and wants to send data to MongoDb. When I console log goalData, the content is correctly what I entered in the input field, but logging the response.data, shows following content: {message: 'Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0', stack: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at positio…ejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)'}. And there is no entry in my Database.
Here my code:

```
const createGoal = async (goalData, token)=>{
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }
    console.log(config);
    console.log(goalData);
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, goalData, config);
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
}
```

Here is my goalsSlice, perhaps it makes it clearer:

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import goalsService from "./goalsService";
const initialState = {
    goals:[],
    isLoading:false,
    isError:false,
    isSuccess:false,
    message:"",
}
//Create new Goal
export const createGoal = createAsyncThunk('goals/create', async (goalData, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
        return await goalsService.createGoal(goalData, 'utf-8', token)
    }catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
                        && error.response.data 
                         && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString()
                         return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
//Get Goals
export const getGoals = createAsyncThunk("goals/getAll", async (_, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
        return await goalsService.getGoals(token)
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
            && error.response.data 
             && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString()
             return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
//deleteGoal
export const deleteGoal = createAsyncThunk("goals/delete", async ( id, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
        return await goalsService.deleteGoal(id, token)
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
            && error.response.data 
             && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString()
             return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})         
export const goalsSlice = createSlice({
    name:"goals",
    initialState, 
    reducers: {
        reset: state=>initialState
    },
    extraReducers: (builder)=>{
        builder
        .addCase(createGoal.pending, (state)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(createGoal.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.goals.push(action.payload);
        })
        .addCase(createGoal.rejected, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.message = action.payload
        })
        .addCase(getGoals.pending, (state)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(getGoals.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.goals = action.payload
        })
        .addCase(getGoals.rejected, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.message = action.payload
        })
        .addCase(deleteGoal.pending, (state)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(deleteGoal.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.goals = state.goals.filter((goal)=>goal._id !== action.payload.id)
        })
        .addCase(deleteGoal.rejected, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.message = action.payload
        })
    }
})
export const {reset} = goalsSlice.actions
export default goalsSlice.reducer
```

My Server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const colors = require("colors");
const {errorHandler} = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const connectDb = require("./config/db");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
connectDb();

const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use("/api/goals", require("./routes/goalRoutes"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/userRoutes"));

app.use(errorHandler);
app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server is running on Port ${port}`));
```

My goalsRoute:

```
const express=require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { getGoals, setGoal, updateGoal, deleteGoal } = require("../controller/goalController");
const {protect} = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
router.route("/").get(protect, getGoals).post(protect, setGoal);
router.route("/:id").put(protect, updateGoal).delete(protect, deleteGoal);

module.exports = router;
```

My goalController:

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const Goal = require("../models/goalModel");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

const getGoals = asyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
    const goals = await Goal.find({ user: req.user.id });
    res.status(200).json(goals);
})
const setGoal = asyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
    if(!req.body.text){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("Please add a text field");
    }
    const goal = await Goal.create({
        text: req.body.text,
        user: req.user.id
    })
    res.status(200).json(goal);
})

const updateGoal = asyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
    const goal = await Goal.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id);

    if(!goal){
        res.status.apply(400);
        throw new Error("Goal not found");
    }
    if(!req.user){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }
    if(goal.user.toString() !== req.user.id){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("Not authorized");
    }

    const updatedgoal = await Goal.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new:true});
    res.status(200).json(updatedgoal);
})

const deleteGoal = asyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
    const goal = await Goal.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    if(!goal){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("Goal not found");
    }
     
     if(!req.user){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }
    
    if(goal.user.toString() !== req.user.id){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("Not authorized");
    }

    await goal.deleteOne();
    res.status(200).json({id: req.params.id})
})

module.exports = {
    getGoals,
    setGoal,
    updateGoal,
    deleteGoal,
}
```

My goalModel:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const goalSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
    text: {type:String, required:true},
    user:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref:'User'},
    
}, {timestamps:true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Goal", goalSchema);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The data in `goalData` might look correct to you but it seems like where ever you are posting it to was expecting it in JSON format but your data is either not in that format or there is a mistake in the formatting. If you post the data logged by `console.log(goalData)` it will probably be clearer what the issue is.

Comment: Hello arfi720, thanks for your answer. goalData is a string.I post it into the node api. That works with postman, but not out of my frontend. In my mongoose model I signed it as type: String, and I post it together with the Jsonwebtoken. The console.log of goalData gives back exactly the text, which I entered in my input field. Delete and Get requests are working from my frontend. What could be the reason that Mongo expects a Json format?

Comment: Thank you arfi720. I edit the content into my question.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your node api? Like any functions that the `goalData` would pass through? The error is probably originating there and being returned to your frontend. Also, if it works in Postman, add the body of the post request your send there?

Comment: Added all code out of the node api. The body in Postman key: text value: New Goal

Comment: You can probably solve this by, instead of sending just a string as the body of your post, you send an object with a string called `text` as that is what you seem to be trying to access in your controller `req.body.text`; Something like `const postBody = {text: goalData}`. Then send `postBody` in the axios call instead of `goalData`.

Comment: That's great to hear! I posted answer with that info, if you wouldn't mind accepting it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are sending only a string as the `body` of your axios post call.

At a minimum, your back end is looking for a an object in JSON format with a property called text:

```
const postBody = {text: goalData};
//the use that object as the body of the post call
const response = await axios.post(API_URL, postBody, config);
```